# create sum of sales per partnumber per calendar week in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have an invoice-line table that lists column of stock-code, quantity, transdate. Boss wants to see how much quantity of each stock sold during past 12 weeks, list as stock-code, week0 (this calendar week), week1, ..., week11.

I used the following script to generate week0 per stock-code table, but can't put week1 ~ week11 into the same table:

```
set datefirst 1;

select 
    stockcode, sum(quantity) as TotalSaleOfWeek0
from 
    DR_INVLINES
where 
    TRANSDATE > (getdate() - DATEPART(dw,getdate())) 
    and QUANTITY <> 0
group by 
    STOCKCODE;
```

Please help..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which day does the week start and end? There is a function to get the day in the week - that allows you to calcuatle the first and laste date of a week easily.

Comment: The week starts from Monday and ends with Sunday, which is why set datefirst 1. It is a rolling table depends on when the report is run, but total sales for same item for a past week, should be consistent calendar wise (before it drops off the table).

Comment: Thanks marc_s for editing! This is the first time I post a question here, still learning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
set datefirst 1;

select 
    stockcode, DATEPART(WEEK, TRANSDATE) As Week, sum(quantity) as TotalSaleOfWeek0
from 
    DR_INVLINES
where 
    TRANSDATE > DATEADD(Week, -12, getdate())
    and QUANTITY <> 0
group by 
    STOCKCODE, DATEPART(WEEK, TRANSDATE);
```